# Database migrations for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, migration, data-migration, database-migration

I need a database migration framework for SQL Server, capable of managing both schema changes and data migrations.

I guess I am looking for something similar to django's [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) framework here.

Given the fact that South is tightly coupled with django's ORM, and the fact that there's so many ORMs for SQL Server I guess having just a generic migration framework, enabling you to write and execute in controlled and sequential manner SQL data/schema change scripts should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at [Wizardby](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/) (open source)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) or [dbdeploy](http://code.google.com/p/dbdeploy/wiki/GettingStarted) meets your needs? I've also heard good things about [RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Redgate's migrations solution in Visual Studio is [ReadyRoll](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/readyroll/).

Our SSMS-based solution is [SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/).